# proving a sequence converges without knowing about monotonicity and boundness?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to take the converse approach of the "if a sequence is monotonic and bounded it has a limit". I am given a sequence. I need to prove existence of the limit and find the limit of the sequence. if I find the limit of the sequence does it prove the existence of the limit ?

Comment: "Before I find the limit of the sequence" can you please explain how you are finding the limit of the sequence in your particular case?Because if you've found the limit then of course it exists, but I would like to make things clearer for you if possible, and for this I require more clarity on the issue.

Comment: first I assume the limit exists, then I try to find the limit of the sequence, and I got the answer which means that the limit exists. hence no point in proving that limit exists

Comment: That does not work. For example, if I assume that there is a limit to the sequence $1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,... = (-1)^n$ where we have $a_{n+1} = -a_n$ and $L  = \lim a_n$  , then $L = -L$ after taking limits, giving $L=0$, a clear falsity from the definition of limit. You have to show the limit exists, then and only then can you proceed to try to find the limit. At  this stage, if you are working with a particular problem, state it so I can make the counter even more specific to your problem.

Comment: Okay I got it thanks

Comment: Sure. Now you need to post an answer to this question.